# 403 template displaying instead of 404

Tags: python, django

I want to be able to display a 404 page when any other request occurs. However, when I run the server and perform a POST request with the POSTMAN extension on chrome, I get a 403 display by Django and not the template I created.

[image]

proj/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'', include("index.urls")),
    url(r'auth/', include("userapp.urls"))
)
```

index/urls.py

```
 urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', load_index),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

)
```

index/views.py

```
def load_index(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = RegistrationForm(auto_id=False)
        return render(request, "index/index.html", {"form": form})
    else:
        # output 404 error
        return render(request, "error/404.html", status=404)
```

Comment: The issue is, since you are using a django form, you need the `{{csrf_token}}` data included as a part of the POST. Alternatively, for development purposes, you can use the `@csrf_exempt` decorator, and then figure out a clean way of including the management data (csrf)

Comment: @karthikr so ANY type of POST request requires the passing of a csrf token? I am not using forms in a POST request.

Comment: I see the form sent in context in the view

Comment: @karthikr I only pass the form when a GET request occurs. A post will not generate the form.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a Django web application, **`POST/PUT/DELETE`** requires the `csrf token`. It's kind of a security policy which Django follows.

Now, why is this required? Because, django web applications by conventions are app's that would have been run with keeping in mind the context of display and usage.

What you are trying to use is the Client like **`POSTMAN`** which is used mainly to test the REST services. (It does not mean you cannot fire requests for an web application that is hosted to work as an Html template).

Now, if you want to provide a **POST**able API from your Django web application, consider the `@csrf_exempt`. The best name given for a topic: [csrf-protection-should-be-disabled-for-just-a-few-views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#csrf-protection-should-be-disabled-for-just-a-few-views).

If you want your application to have, it's usage as a RESTFul service, make sure you use the right tool, might be [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/). (Note: Using `@csrf_extempt` is also a way for you, if you are providing an API to your site, which would provide some views as an API for POST/PUT).